# The size of data types in C and Java?

Tags: java, c

The size of the data type in C for example, int is 2 bytes, however the size of int in Java is 4 bytes, and the same for other data types as well. Why is the size of a data type double in Java?

Comment: "The size of the data type in C for example, int is 2 bytes" - no, it's implementation-specific.

Comment: It really depends, in the C I use (Linux gcc on Ubuntu) int is 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

The size of data types in C is implementation specific. For 16 bit machines, int is 2 bytes, for 32 bit machines it is 4 bytes, and for 64 bit machines, it is 4, or 8 bytes.  (Visual Studios 2019 on Windows 10 yields 4 bytes, whereas FCC on my Linux machine yields 8 bytes.)

To check your int size, please use 'sizeof(int)'.

C compilers can also define int16_t, or int32_t, or int64_t, as well as int16, int32, and int64, just to make things fun.  It's what happens when you have nearly a half century of history slapped onto a language. This is why sizeof is so important, as hard coding a size may work with one compiler but may not work with another.

Comment: “16 bit machines,” “32 bit machines,” and so on are not proper terms. Computer processors are complex devices with many characteristics, including register widths, bus widths, address space sizes, and so on. These may have mixed values, such as 16-bit registers with a 22-bit address space, in which case the machine is not distinctly 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit. The width of `int` is intended to be the “natural” size suggested by the architecture, but it and the widths of other integer types is determined by the C implementation, not the machine.

Answer (score 1):

C specifies minimum type sizes, and there's variability between implementations as to the actual sizes they use.  Java, on the other hand, specifies exact type sizes, so there's no variability between implementations.

Some programmers always like to specify the exact size of every type.  If you do, you will probably like Java better.  Or, in C, you can include the header `<inttypes.h>` and use C's exact-size types like `int16_t` and `int32_t`.

But in answer to your question, "Why are types twice as big in Java?", that's unanswerable, becauae the premise of the question is flawed.  You said, "in C for example, int is 2 bytes", but that's not true.  The *minimum guaranteed* size is 2 bytes, but on most popular machines today it's 4.

Answer (score 0):

C and Java have different approaches to portability.

Since compiled C code (typically) runs natively, the C specification avoids mandating specific sizes, since that will vary among different machines.  Instead, it specifies a *minimum range of values* that each type must be able to represent.  An `int` must be able to represent *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide, but it may be wider.  On modern desktop platforms it’s typically 32 bits wide.

Compiled Java code, OTOH, (typically) runs in a virtual machine (basically a machine level interpreter), and the VM is specified such that types always have a fixed size.  The VM is the responsible for mapping Java types onto the native machine, so a VM running on a 16-bit platform may have to do some interesting gymnastics to represent a 32-bit `int`.